# MySQL selecting entries when true and replace with null when false

Tags: mysql, sql

I am programming an office schedule.

I have a table `users` in which each user has a regular schedule `hreg` that is monday to friday.

I have a table `hleave` in which I enter a leave code for the dates a user is out of office.

Table `hleave`:

```
hleave_id   user        dateStart   dateEnd     leaveCode
int(11)PK   int(11)FK   date        date        int(11)FK
1           5           2019-02-11  2019-02-13  1
2           1           2019-02-28  2019-02-28  1
3           3           2019-02-26  2019-02-28  2
```

Table `users`:

```
user_id     firstName   lastName    link_team_id    link_hreg_id
int(11)PK   varchar     varchar     int(11)FK       int(11)FK
1           Bob         Smith       1               1
2           Alice       Fraser      1               1
3           Jenny       Summers     1               1
4           Carl        Raisman     1               1
5           Roger       Wayne       1               1
```

Table `teams`:

```
team_id     teamName
int(11)PK   varchar
1           team 1
2           team 2
3           team 3
```

Table `hreg`:

```
hreg_id     weekStart   weekEnd
int(11)PK   int(11)     int(11)
1           1           5
2           1           4
3           2           5
```

Table `leave_codes`:

```
code_id     codeName
int(11)PK   varchar
1           A
2           B 
3           C
4           D
```

If there is an hleave entry with a date range that either starts this week, ends this week or starts before this week and ends after this week, I want to display the leave code.

If not, I want to display the user's regular schedule "working". For example:

```
        Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday
BOB     working working working     A           working
ALICE   working working working     working     working
JENNY   working B       B           B           working
CARL    working working working     working     working
```

Here is my query for TEAM #1 (I replaced the variables $monday and $friday with real dates for clarity) :

```sql
SELECT 
    users.firstName,
    users.lastName,
    users.link_team_id,
    users.link_hreg_id,
    hreg.weekStart,
    hreg.weekEnd,
    leave_codes.codeName,
    hleave.dateStart,
    hleave.dateEnd
FROM users
    LEFT JOIN hleave ON hleave.user = users.user_id
    JOIN teams ON users.link_team_id = teams.team_id 
    JOIN hreg ON users.link_hreg_id = hreg.hreg_id
    LEFT JOIN leave_codes ON hleave.leaveCode = leave_codes.code_id
WHERE
    (CASE 
        WHEN (hleave.dateStart BETWEEN '2019-02-25' AND '2019-03-01')
            THEN (users.link_team_id = 1)
        WHEN (hleave.dateEnd BETWEEN '2019-02-25' AND '2019-03-01')
            THEN (users.link_team_id = 1)
        WHEN (hleave.dateStart < '2019-02-25' AND hleave.dateEnd > '2019-03-01')
            THEN (users.link_team_id = 1)
        WHEN (hleave.dateStart IS NULL AND hleave.dateEnd IS NULL)
            THEN (users.link_team_id = 1)
    END)
```

Results:

```
firstName   lastName    link_team_id    link_hreg_id    weekStart   weekEnd     codeName    dateStart   dateEnd
Bob         Smith       1               1               1           5           A           2019-02-28  2019-02-28
Alice       Fraser      1               1               1           5           NULL        NULL        NULL
Jenny       Summers     1               1               1           5           B           2019-02-26  2019-02-28
Carl        Raisman     1               1               1           5           NULL        NULL        NULL
```

This query works. I get the `codeName`, `dateStart` and `dateEnd` for a user if it happens this week. If `dateStart` and `dateEnd` are NULL, I still get the user `firstName`, `lastName` and `hreg` so I can display them on the website as working.

So far so good, but I have a problem. When `dateStart < '2019-02-25'` and `dateEnd < '2019-03-01'` (i.e. if the leave happened before this week) I get nothing for this user since the date range validates as FALSE and it is not NULL either. For instance, if Roger had a leave on 2019-02-11 to 2019-02-13, Roger is not included in the results set.

Same thing goes for a date range in the future : `dateStart > '2019-02-25'` and `dateEnd> '2019-03-01'`.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I tried CASE WHEN in the SELECT clause to pin poit the dates I want to select but the result is the same. I either need to select differently or to turn entries validating as FALSE to NULL?

Comment: Please provide sample data for all tables involved: `users`, `hleave`, `teams`, `hreg`, `leave_codes`, and the corresponding expected output. As it is, it is hard to relate your query to the expected results.

Comment: I included a results sample

Comment: Please provide the schema and preferably some sample data for each of the tables. From the looks of things, it appears that you may be making this more complex than it has to be.

Comment: I included all tables with data

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - although I would observe that the usual test for overlaps is if one event starts before the other ends, and ends after the other starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, it appears that you're making the query a bit more complex than needed.

The main issue is the `CASE/WHEN` in your `WHERE` criteria, limiting the `users` to those matching in the `CASE/WHEN`, Since Roger was on leave, but did not match the specified dates in the `WHERE` criteria, he was excluded.

As you appear to only be interested in a specific team, the user team can be filtered directly in your main query. Presuming `hleave` only contains an entry when the `user` is on leave for the date range queried, the condition can be moved from your WHERE to the LEFT JOIN, displaying `NULL` when the user is not on leave.

```
SELECT 
users.firstName,
users.lastName,
users.link_team_id,
users.link_hreg_id,
hreg.weekStart,
hreg.weekEnd,
leave_codes.codeName,
hleave.dateStart,
hleave.dateEnd
FROM users
JOIN teams 
ON users.link_team_id = teams.team_id
JOIN hreg 
ON users.link_hreg_id = hreg.hreg_id
LEFT JOIN hleave 
ON hleave.user = users.user_id
AND (
    hleave.dateStart BETWEEN '2019-02-25' AND '2019-03-01' #leave starts this week
    OR
    hleave.dateEnd BETWEEN '2019-02-25' AND '2019-03-01' #leave ends this week
    OR
    (hleave.dateStart < '2019-02-25' AND hleave.dateEnd > '2019-03-01') #leave started before this week and continues after
)
LEFT JOIN leave_codes 
ON hleave.leaveCode = leave_codes.code_id
WHERE users.link_team_id = 1
```

Results in:

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">firstName</th>
          <th class="col1">lastName</th>
          <th class="col2">link_team_id</th>
          <th class="col3">link_hreg_id</th>
          <th class="col4">weekStart</th>
          <th class="col5">weekEnd</th>
          <th class="col6">codeName</th>
          <th class="col7">dateStart</th>
          <th class="col8">dateEnd</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">Bob</td>
          <td class="col1">Smith</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">1</td>
          <td class="col5">5</td>
          <td class="col6">A</td>
          <td class="col7">2019-02-28</td>
          <td class="col8">2019-02-28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">Jenny</td>
          <td class="col1">Summers</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">1</td>
          <td class="col5">5</td>
          <td class="col6">B</td>
          <td class="col7">2019-02-26</td>
          <td class="col8">2019-02-28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">Alice</td>
          <td class="col1">Fraser</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">1</td>
          <td class="col5">5</td>
          <td class="col6"></td>
          <td class="col7"></td>
          <td class="col8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">Carl</td>
          <td class="col1">Raisman</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">1</td>
          <td class="col5">5</td>
          <td class="col6"></td>
          <td class="col7"></td>
          <td class="col8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">Roger</td>
          <td class="col1">Wayne</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">1</td>
          <td class="col4">1</td>
          <td class="col5">5</td>
          <td class="col6"></td>
          <td class="col7"></td>
          <td class="col8"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I tested it and it works as intended! I knew I wasn't that far off but I would have never thought about the conditions in the LEFT JOIN. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to solve your question.

To start with, let's join together the 5 tables. The trick here is to `LEFT JOIN` the `hleaves` table by checking if a leave interval *overlaps* with the week being filtered; the classic way is to use an expression like: `l.dateStart < @weekEnd AND l.dateEnd < @weekStart`:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    users u
    INNER JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = u.link_team_id
    INNER JOIN hreg  r ON r.hreg_id = u.link_hreg_id
    LEFT JOIN hleave l ON l.user = u.user_id AND l.dateStart < @weekEnd AND l.dateEnd < @weekStart
    LEFT JOIN leave_codes lc ON lc.code_id = l.leaveCode
```

With this dataset in place, we can now use *conditional aggregation* to produce the desired results. For example, to check for the status on Tuesday, we would do:

```
MAX(
    CASE 
        -- employee on leave
        WHEN DATE_ADD(@weekStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN l.dateStart AND l.dateEnd THEN lc.codeName
        -- employee on schedule for that day
        WHEN 2 BETWEEN h.weekStart AND h.weekEnd THEN 'working'
        -- employee not on schedule for that day
        ELSE 'not working'
    END
) AS Tuesday
```

You can repeat this expression for each day of the week, incrementing the counters. Here is the query for Monday through Wednesday:

```
SELECT
    u.firstName,    
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN @weekStart BETWEEN l.dateStart AND l.dateEnd THEN lc.codeName
            WHEN 2 BETWEEN h.weekStart AND h.weekEnd THEN 'working'
            ELSE 'not working'
        END
    ) AS Monday,
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN DATE_ADD(@weekStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN l.dateStart AND l.dateEnd THEN lc.codeName
            WHEN 2 BETWEEN h.weekStart AND h.weekEnd THEN 'working'
            ELSE 'not working'
        END
    ) AS Tuesday,
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN DATE_ADD(@weekStart, INTERVAL 2 DAY) BETWEEN l.dateStart AND l.dateEnd THEN lc.codeName
            WHEN 3 BETWEEN h.weekStart AND h.weekEnd THEN 'working'
            ELSE 'not working'
        END
    ) AS Wednesday
    -- other days go here
FROM 
    users u
    INNER JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = u.link_team_id
    INNER JOIN hreg  r ON r.hreg_id = u.link_hreg_id
    LEFT JOIN hleave l ON l.user = u.user_id AND l.dateStart < @weekEnd AND l.dateEnd < @weekStart
    LEFT JOIN leave_codes lc ON lc.code_id = l.leaveCode
GROUP BY
    u.user_id,
    u.firstName
```

Comment: The thing is I've already written all the php code to display either the leave codeName or "working" for the results. Your answer seems very professional and I will try to understand it but the solution provided by fyrye is easier for me to replicate and eventually debug. Can you tell me the benefits of this solution over fyrye's?

Comment: @turboisturbo: my answer would produce the output that you described, with **one column for each day of the week**. AFAIK Fryrye's query does not.

Comment: @turboisturbo : regarding the `'not working'` status : for an employee whose team schedule starts on Tuesday (ie `hreg.weekStart = 2`), what do you want to display in column `Monday`?

Comment: This is accounted for with php when I parse the results :
`if ($mondayFull >= $dateStart AND $mondayFull <= $dateEnd){
echo '<td><span style="color: var(--'.$codeColor.')">'.$codeName.'</span></td>';
} else 
if ($mondayDay >= $weekStart AND $mondayDay <= $weekEnd){
echo '<td>bureau</td>';
} else {
echo '<td> - </td>';
}`

Comment: @turboisturbo: ok I see, well it's the same logic in SQL (so less work for the PHP presentation layer).

Comment: @turboisturbo if you can adapt this query for your purposes, it is best to produce the results from the query from a reporting sense, as that is SQL's purpose. Additionally will improve performance on the application side, significantly more so with query caching techniques. I was writing out the same when GMB submitted his answer, so submitted mine.